# Javascript preserving a URL parameter on page change

Tags: javascript, query-string, window.location

I'm using Vanilla Javascript,

I have two pages, `page01.html` and `page02.html` these pages share the same navigation system.

I want to load a parameter into the url of `page01`, and after I click `page02` on navigation, `page02` will load with the parameter within its URL.

example:

1. I'm on `page01.html`
2. I load a param into the URL, so now I have page01.html/?param=X
3. I click the menu item page02
4. I want to load page02.html/?param=X

Is there any way to do this without using localStorage and sessionStorage?

Comment: Just `el.href += location.search` on the menu link `el`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used both Bergi's comment and Henry's answer to create my own version.

Basically I just created a `onclick="menuClick();"` and an `id="menuLink"` on the a tag. 
Then on the Javascript I just added the `location.search` to the href:

```
menuClick = function() {
    document.getElementById('menuLink').href += location.search
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using vanilla JavaScript:

**Page01.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>Page 1</div>

<a href="page02.html">go to page 2</a>

<script>
   var linkToPage2 = document.querySelector("a[href='page02.html']");
   linkToPage2.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     if(location.search){
       window.location.href = "page02.html" + location.search; 
     }
 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page02.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>Page 2</div>

<a href="page01.html">go to page 1</a>

<script>
    var linkToPage1 = document.querySelector("a[href='page01.html']");
    linkToPage1.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        if(location.search){ 
             window.location.href = "page01.html" + location.search;
         }
     });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```